# Handling custom blur and focus events with vue-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-select

I’m having a small issue with some custom blur and focus behaviours, using the [vue-select](https://vue-select.org/) component.

I’m attempting to override the blur behaviour of the component, if a user clicks away and onto a specific, predefined target - for example, if the user clicks onto `#special-place` while a select is open, the select should remain open until any other element receives focus.

The code below gets me most of the way there, but there is a small bug: if a dropdown is open and *another select component* is clicked, the second one remains then open regardless of any subsequent clicks. [Here’s a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wind-3tf7r), with a live example.

Template is as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-select
    @search:blur="customBlurHandler"
    :options="options"
    :filterable="false"
    :ref="reference"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    label="name"
  >
    <!-- Remove caret icon -->
    <div slot="open-indicator"></div>
  </v-select>
</template>
```

The relevant methods are below (not the best named, I know):

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: ["one", "two", "three"],
      isBlurHandlerActive: false,
      reference: `${this.locationType}Select`
    };
  },
  props: ["locationType", "placeholder"],
  name: "CustomSelector",
  components: { vSelect },

  methods: {
    clickHandler(event) {
      const specialClicked = event.target.closest("#special-place") !== null;
      if (specialClicked) return;
      else {
        this.isBlurHandlerActive = true;
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
        this.forceOptionsClosed();
      }
    },

    customBlurHandler() {
      if (this.isBlurHandlerActive) {
        this.isBlurHandlerActive = false;
        return;
      } else {
        this.forceOptionsOpen();
        document.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
      }
    },

    forceOptionsClosed() {
      this.$refs[this.reference].open = false;
      this.$refs[this.reference].searchEl.blur();
    },

    forceOptionsOpen() {
      this.$refs[this.reference].open = true;
      this.$refs[this.reference].searchEl.focus();
    }
  }
};
```

I’m also aware this might not be the most vue-like way to approach the problem, so if there’s a better way to solve this, I’m open to suggestions.

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue in Chrome.

Comment: @AlexMA Which version? I'm testing in 80.0.3987.149

Comment: Or maybe I’m not trying the right thing? I’m using the same

Comment: @AlexMA In the sandbox, if you first click on "To" and then on "From", if you then click on the body the dropdown stays open (for me, at least), but it should close.

Comment: Got it, now I see the issue